# How to find substring in string in Lotus Script Querysave

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a field called `Status` which i query with  `source.FieldGetText("Status")` in my `Querysave`.

This Status can be either

- one
- two
- two | three
- two | three | four

now my problem is with [`Instr`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_INSTR_FUNCTION.html):

```
If Instr("two",Status) > 0 Then...
```

returns for each Status are:

- 0
- 1
- 0
- 0

Why doesn't it return 1 for Case 3 & 4 as in Case 2?
As i understand it Instr Checks if the substring is in the String and returns it's position which should be 1 for Case 3 & 4 aswell?

Just for reference in Python i would do this:

```
if "test" in "this is a test":
    print("String contains test")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work the other way around:

```
If Instr(status, "two") > 0 Then..
```

[Instr()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_INSTR_FUNCTION.html) first parameter is the string you search in, the second is the string you search for.